# Convert A Column and Column B In Pandas to One Long String (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKyrp.png)How can I convert a pandas columns into one long string?

For example, convert the following DF:

```
column1 column2 
John    Noun
Went    Verb
To      DT[enter image description here][2]
Fetch   Verb
His     AD
Ball    Noun
```

To read as

Keyword
`John/Noun went/Verb to/DT fetch/Verb his/AD Ball/Noun`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join columns together with separator and call `join`:

```
s = ' '.join(df['Keyword'] + '/' + df['Tag'])
```

Or use [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
s = ' '.join(df['Keyword'].str.cat(df['Tag'], sep='/'))
```

If need join all columns use `apply`:

```
s = ' '.join(df.apply( '/'.join, axis=1))
#if possible some non strings columns
#s = ' '.join(df.astype(str).apply( '/'.join, axis=1))
```

---

```
print (s)
John/Noun Went/Verb To/DT Fetch/Verb His/AD Ball/Noun To read/as
```